# C++ "undefined reference to" function error

Tags: c++, undefined

I've been having some problems compiling this code for mergesort on an array of custom data types. The undefined reference is in response to

```
mergesort(hw1type*, int)
```

Here are the relevant code snips leaving out the includes, and what not, which I know all work:

Main (Where the error is propagating to):

```
hw1type * unsorted_array2 = new hw1type[SIZE];

unsorted_array2 = create_random_hw1type(SIZE);

mergesort(unsorted_array2, SIZE);
```

mergesort.h:

```
hw1type* mergesort(hw1type*, int);
hw1type* merge(hw1type*, int, hw1type*, int);
```

mergesort.cc:

```
hw1type mergesort(hw1type* unsorted_array, int n)
```

I can't see anything wrong with the way the functions are declared, or the way I'm passing the variables in main. But, it's been a while since I've used c++ so I could use a second or third pair of eyes!

Edit: Turns out it was the make file, I forgot to change. It's always something simple.

Ah, right, I was using the standard make file that came with the other classes.Anyway, here's that code:

I should probably throw mergesort.o into the list of OBJs, but anything else? The make file looks like this:

```
CC=gcc
CXX=c++
CFLAGS=-ggdb -O3 -I. 
LDFLAGS=-L. -lcs600

OBJ=timer.o random_generator.o sort.o

cs600:  libcs600.a main.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) main.o -o hw1 $(LDFLAGS)

libcs600.a: $(OBJ)
    ar ru libcs600.a $(OBJ)
    ranlib libcs600.a

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $<


clean:
    @rm -f *.o
    @rm -f libcs600.a
    @rm -f hw1
```

I need to add mergesort.o to the OBJ field, but anything other than that? Considering it's been a while for C++, it's really been a while since I've messed around with make files.

Comment: Not that it should cause any undefined reference, but you should use the same return type in the .h and .cc. Are you sure you're linking with mergesort.o included?

Comment: Could you turn this into a complete example (you don't need the body for the `merge` and `mergesort` functions), and include the complete error?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: actually, there are systems where the return type is mangled into the symbol! This is actually a sensible thing to do for multiple reasons: 1. if the function gets defined with a different return type than it is declared this error is caught at link time; 2. the error message for linker errors can contain the complete signature rather than leaving out the return type when showing a demangled symbol. 3. you could actually create a suitable header file declaring the functions defined in a libraryfrom the symbols.

Comment: The return type of `mergesort` is inconsistent.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yes, I always wondered why that wasn't done, but I've never seen a compiler that did it. I assumed it was so that you'd not accidentally overload by return type with the definitions being in two different files. May be the problem then.

Comment: Sun/Oracle's compiler does this for example. The main reason this isn't done is probably that name mangling was invented to cope with overloaded functions and it took people a while to come up with something like c++filt and then to realize that this could work with return types, too. By then, there was already code depending on the C++ ABI which didn't have the return type included.

Answer (score 1):

"Undefined reference" is a link-time error.  Make sure the object file that contains the missing function is part of your link command line.  In your case, probably something like:

```
clang++ -o app main.o mergesort.o
```

Or simply:

```
clang++ -o app main.cc mergesort.cc
```

If you didn't compile each file separately first.

Answer (score 0):

You're not compiling `mergesort.cc` into object code, and/or you're not linking in that object code.

If you're using an IDE, make sure you've added `mergesort.cc` to your project configuration; if you're using Makefiles or compiling on the command line, make sure you include that in the list of source files you're compiling.